# Using for loops to create a grid of widgets in tkinter

Tags: for-loop, tkinter, widget, python-3.6

I'm trying to cut down on the amount of code required to produce a 4x4 grid of buttons in a simple calculator app using tkinter and python 3.6 so far I have made the grid using a separate list and for loop for each row of buttons like below

```
    firstRow = ['1','2','3',] 
    secondRow = ['4','5','6','*']
    thirdRow = ['7','8','9','/']
    forthRow = ['.','0','-','+']


    for b in range(len(firstRow)):
        firstBtns = tk.Button(self, text=firstRow[b],
                              command=lambda i=firstRow[b]: entry.insert('end',i),
                              width=5)
        firstBtns.grid(row=0, column=b)

    for b in range(len(secondRow)):
        secondBtns = tk.Button(self, text=secondRow[b], width=5)
        secondBtns.grid(row=1, column=b)

    for b in range(len(thirdRow)):
        thirdBtns = tk.Button(self, text=thirdRow[b], width=5)
        thirdBtns.grid(row=2, column=b)

    for b in range(len(forthRow)):
        forthBtns = tk.Button(self, text=forthRow[b], width=5)
        forthBtns.grid(row=3, column=b)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using 4 lists within a list, and using a single for loop, or a nested for loop? heres what ive tried but cant get it to display properly.

```
buttonRows = [['1','2','3','AC'],['4','5','6','/'],
                ['7','8','9','*',],['.','0','-','+']] 

    for lst in range(len(buttonRows)):

        for b in buttonRows[lst]:          
            print(len(buttonRows[lst]))
            btns = tk.Button(self, text=b, width=5)
            btns.grid(row=lst, column=lst)
```

heres what it gives me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xUJd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are placing all buttons in each row in the same row and column: `btns.grid(row=lst, column=lst)`.

It's more Pythonic and easier to read the code if you loop over the lists and use enumerate:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

buttonRows = [['1','2','3','AC'],['4','5','6','/'],
              ['7','8','9','*',],['.','0','-','+']] 

for row_index, row in enumerate(buttonRows):
    for cell_index, cell in enumerate(row):
        btns = tk.Button(root, text=cell, width=5)
        btns.grid(row=row_index, column=cell_index)
```

Comment: so we are using enumerate to increment the cell and row index the row being each list and the cell being each item in the list? The row being incremented on after each item has been incremented on within the second loop is that correct?

Comment: Yes. For clarity you may want to make a statement in the inner loop that prints the `row_index`, `cell_index` and the `cell`. You will see how the indexes and cell value changes.

Comment: perfect yeah I made a print statement for each to get a better look at what was going on I remember learning about enumerate a while back and totally forgot what it did. Thank you so much I'm sure ill start using enumerate a lot more now.